# netcat for execute remote ELF file like CTFs

Tags: netcat

I'm trying trying to do a pwn challenge, where you connect with nc to the remote server and this execute a vulnerable ELF file (With a buffer overflow). The problem that I'm having is that I only receive the output from the server side and the input from the client side with the following code:
nc -l  | ./script

Also I tried:
ncat -l  --exec "./script"
In this last case when I do the Buffer Overflow, It doesn't give me any response.

And, other problem with both codes is that when my script for example prints "Give me a word", this print is showed when the execution of the script was finished. I put the word and then the script shows all the prints of the program.

Best regards.

PD: An example of what I'm trying to do - hxxps://github.com/ctfs/write-ups-2015/tree/master/csaw-ctf-2015/pwn/precision-100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `|` and the missing port is most likely the problem. In `ncat -l --exec "./script"` you are missing the listening port again.

Here is a full example that works:

The script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "Give me a line..."
while read ln; do
    echo "I got '$ln'"
    echo "Give me a line..."
done
```

Start a listener

```
nc -l 9999 --exec ./zzz.sh
```

Connect to the script:

```
nc 127.0.0.1 9999
```

you will see

```
Give me a line...
```

type

```
Hello script...
```

and you will see two more lines

```
I got 'Hello script...'
Give me a line...
```

Check if you did not forget to `chmod a+x script.sh`. If `nc` can not execute the script you will get something like:

```
$ nc -l 9999 --exec ./zzz.shs
exec: No such file or directory
```

Also, choose ports in the range [1025 .. 65535], [1 .. 1024] are available only to the root user.

Comment: Thanks ! that was helpful. I added the variable line, maybe someone have the same trouble one day:                 
echo "User:";
read ln;
user=$(echo -n $ln);.

Then I just added some statements for compare and other things and the script goes. Thanks again!